# UITableViewController will not call cellForRowAtIndexPath BUT numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are set properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**Solution:**

The solution was to start by properly starting with a UITableView and then adding the UITableView delegates to the UIViewController as outlined in the selected answer.

**Preface: I have read nearly every article on the matter and nothing advised has helped.**

I'm embedding a UITableViewController's UITableView into a UIViewController.

I understand that nothing will be called unless the view is rendered, so I render it and I can use NSLog to show that it hit those methods.

I tried making a UITableViewController in InterfaceBuilder and setting my subclass as its custom class which worked!! But that's not how I need to go about it. Here's what I've gathered / done:

- I am using InterfaceBuilder to manage the UIViewController but I'm adding the UITableView programmatically
- Both the delegate and dataSource are set properly and self.tableView is not nil
- Despite the valid logging, cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called and the rendered UITableView is blank
- I added the  delegates to my controller which did not change anything

I have set the following on the UITableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.questions); // This outputs the questions array as not empty and works
    // As you can see I am also returning 1.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [self.questions count]); // This outputs 4 as it should
    return [self.questions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // All we need to focus on is this NSLog which never outputs
    NSLog(@"Was called and array is, %@" self.questions);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}
```

I've tried setting the view many ways: Adding UITableViewController directly, adding the UITableViewController's UITableView (which seems to be the correct way), but nothing is working.

Perhaps there is a major step I have forgotten when when working with InterfaceBuilder or some random thing I have forgotten. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

** UPDATE **
Here is how I add either the UiTableViewController or the UITavleView

```
GTTableViewController *tvc = [[GTTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
// Either
[self.view addSubview:tvc.view];
// OR
[self.view addSubview:tvc.tableView];
// Just to make sure everything is still ok.. and I see the 2/3 TV methods fire.
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: What if you simplified your code and write: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ return 4; }

Comment: "I'm embedding a UITableViewController's UITableView into a UIViewController." What do you mean by this? Are you just adding a table view to a UIViewController, or do you have a UITableViewController involved somehow?

Comment: @edzio27 I tried that, nothing.

Comment: So you want a table view in the view hierarchy of some view controller. Why is there a `UITableViewController` involved? Generally, you don't want to embed one controller's view into another controller's view unless you're explicitly implementing controller containment. Can you show the code where you create and "add" the table?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm doing [self.view addSubview:tableViewController.tableView]; which may not the best way, but neither adding TVC or a TC to the UiViewController's view works.

Comment: This is your problem. You can't do that without using container controllers. Just add a table view to your controller. You shouldn't be involving a table view controller at all.

Comment: @rdelmar Would you mind providing an example or link to where I can find a good example of programmatically a custom UITableView?

Comment: Also, why can't you use your GTTableViewController directly? Why are you embedding its table view in another controller?

Comment: @rdelmar is correct. What I would like to add is - when you init a UITableViewController like that, you don't know what all it ought to do (apart from initing itself) to get the whole thing working. Plus, there are minimal requirements defined by Apple for any view controller to act like a table view controller: just implement the right delegates and you are done. See my answer, followed by Apple documentation for those delegates and you should be all set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to analyze your code, I will show you a simple example how to programmatically add a table view to a view controller that is **not** a `UITableViewController`. Hopefully this will help you getting your problem ironed out by yourself.

In the .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
}
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
- (void) loadView
{
  CGRect mainViewFrame = CGRectMake(...);
  self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainViewFrame] autorelease];

  // You could make this even simpler if you set the table view as
  // your main view
  CGRect tableViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
  UITableView* tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
  [self.view addSubview:tableView];

  tableView.delegate = self;
  tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

That's pretty much it. Nothing spectacular, but with this simple setup the `UITableViewDataSource` data source methods should be happily triggering, including `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. At least they do here...

I suggest you take this example and make it work in your environment. Then you slowly rework it step-by-step into the design you want. At some point things will stop working, then you will have the source of your problem.

Comment: I wanna thank everyone for their help and advice. I now understand how to properly add a UITableView to the UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The enclosing UIViewController is the container controller of the UITableViewController. 
The UIViewController documentation has a section on this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81

I have a similar case, where adding a call to the method "addChildViewController" fixes the issue:

```
[self addChildViewController:tvc];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the frame for the tableView?  You can print it with `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));`.  On a hunch, it's 0,0,0,0.

Answer (score 0):

1 - check what numberOfRowsInSection returns. Does it returns value > 0? (sounds stupid I too made such mistakes)

2 - In your IB, check the table view cell type - is it static or dynamic? If static it won't even look at your code.

3 -  Are you calling reloaddata at proper place?

4 - In your view controller header file (or wherever it is declared), are you inheriting from delegates UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource?